# How to assign package to dynamically created structure/table type/program

Tags: abap

I'm creating dynamic structure and table type with  DDIF_TABL_PUT and   DDIF_TTYP_PUT fm's. I cant find package parameter in input parameters for these function modules so I used TR_TADIR_INTERFACE to assign package to my dynamically created objects. But beside it creates a record in TADIR table i can't see newly created objects in my local object tree.

Is this the right way to assign package to dynamically created objects and if not how to do it?
Also can I use this fm to assign package for program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `RPY_TABLE_*` function modules instead since they cover TADIR and access control handling as well. Other than that, try updating the object list of the package (context menu action in SE80) - it is a common occurrence that generated objects do not appear in the UI because some buffer was not reset properly.

Comment: Cool, updating object list worked. I'll look into fm's you mentioned. Thx!